# Convert character values to specific date format

Tags: r

I have character values that are stored like this

```
Date <- x("05/05/15", "06/06/15")
df <- data.frame(Date)
```

Now I would like to convert these dates into a format: YYYY-MM-DD but doing this:

```
df$Date <- format(as.Date("%d/%m/%Y", df$Date))
```

Does not work. Any thoughts on how I can convert it?

Answer (score 1):

We need to use `format = "%d/%m/%y"` i.e. `y` instead of `Y` as the 'year' part is only 2 digits

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%d/%m/%y") 
df$Date
#[1] "2015-05-05" "2015-06-06"
```

Or use `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(df$Date)
```